# Cauchy's Theorem for complex integrals with a condition

Tags: complex-analysis, boundary-value-problem

Does Cauchy's Theorem for complex integrals hold if I have the following scenario:

I integrate a function $f$ which is analytic (holomorphic) over a region $A$ except for a point $z_0$.

1. If that point $z_0$ is inside the region, when does Cauchy's Theorem hold?
2. If that point $z_0$ is on the boundary of that region, when does Cauchy's Theorem hold?

Thanks.

Comment: It's certainly true if $z_0$ is a removable singularity.

Comment: Are you talking about the theorem that says the integral of a holomorphic function around a closed contour is zero?  If so, the function really does have to be holomorphic there, altho as user1337 says its okay if the singularity is removable.  However, if it is a pole or essential singularity, you do not get zero.